# How do you remove an app from Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive

A while ago, I installed [DriveTunes](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/drivetunes/labgcacinobdnkfndodfkfeabbjckbnj) to play music from Google Drive. Now, it annoys me.

I've already:

- removed the Chrome extension
- revoked DriveTunes access to my files
- revoked DriveTunes authorization from my account (https://www.google.com/settings/security)

Yet, it's still there and I get the DriveTunes icon on my documents.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're going to want to open the **Settings** menu, then **Manage Apps**:

[image]

Then, **disconnect** the app

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**As of January 2019**, this direct link takes you straight to where you need to look:

> https://myaccount.google.com/permissions

If you have multiple Google accounts, you can use the account switcher in the top-right corner to review third-party access permissions across all your Google accounts.